# How to script video generation from text (captions, credits, title sequences, ...)?

Tags: video, text, scripting

I need to generate a title sequence, as well as credits and so on, for thousands of videos.  For each video I can and will have a file in whatever appropriate format describing the desired text for the opening and closing sequences, as well as how long each page of text should be shown.

What software exists that can be used for this?  It needs to be scriptable/automatable, as I have thousands of videos to do this for.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to render final videos(including text,caption,title etc..). In this case you can see After Effects Scripting. [Here](http://ae.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow/introduction-to-the-basics-of-after-effects-scripting/) is a video demonstrating scripting basics in AE.